# In a Typescript declaration, how to have one value dependent to the type of another?

Tags: typescript

I have the following code:

```js
type ValidationResult = 'OK' | 'MISSING_FIELDS' | 'DUPLICATED_FIELD';

type ValidationResultOkDetails = null;
type ValidationResultMissingFieldsDetails = [string];
type ValidationResultDuplicatedField = string;

type Validation = {
  result: ValidationResult,
  details: any
}
```

Is there a way in Typescript to tell the compiler that when the field `result` of `Validation` is 'OK', `details` is of type `ValidationResultOkDetails`, when it is 'MISSING_FIELDS', `details` should be `ValidationResultMissingFieldsDetails` and so on?

Answer (score 2):

```
type Validation = {
  result: 'OK',
  details: ValidationResultOkDetails
} | {
  result: 'MISSING_FIELDS',
  details: ValidationResultMissingFieldsDetails
};
```

This is a bit messy, but it's the nicest way I know of to solve the problem. Others may know more.

Comment: Relevant documentation: [discriminated unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions)

Answer (score 2):

Given that `OK` has no data, here is how I would do it (with example for usage / checking).
The compiler "knows" how to narrow down to whichever type based on the signal value in `result`.

I've declared the individual types separately, but they could be just done inline with the `Validation` declaration if desired (keep them separate if you need to refer to any of them explicitly).

```
type ValidationResult = 'OK' | 'MISSING_FIELDS' | 'DUPLICATED_FIELD';

type ValidationResultOkDetails = null;
type ValidationResultMissingFieldsDetails = [string];
type ValidationResultDuplicatedField = string;

type ValidationOK = {
    result: 'OK',
}

type validationMissing = {
    result: 'MISSING_FIELDS',
    details: ValidationResultMissingFieldsDetails,
}

type validationDuplicated = {
    result: 'DUPLICATED_FIELD',
    details: ValidationResultDuplicatedField,
}

type Validation = ValidationOK | validationMissing | validationDuplicated;

const ok: Validation = {
    result: 'OK',
}

const missing: Validation = {
    result: 'MISSING_FIELDS',
    details: ['x'],
}

const duplicated: Validation = {
    result: 'DUPLICATED_FIELD',
    details: 'hello',
}

function handle(v: Validation) {
    if (v.result === 'OK') {
        // no details
    } else if (v.result === 'MISSING_FIELDS') {
        // [string]
        const m = v.details[0];
    } else if (v.result === 'DUPLICATED_FIELD') {
        // string
        const d = v.details;
    }
}
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAaghgGwJYBM7CQewHYCUIDOArgsFALxQDkA8gNJVQA+1AsgJIDKn7AcgOIB9AGLsAogBkAIp0YsqUgKoAFCewDCAQQAqYqSPHSqAbgCwAKAuhIsRKnRY8hEsBoBrKRGBwkCAhShsEgQzc2toeGQ0DBx8YlJWJAICJGwAc2EkCAQUAk9vX39KAG0CYAAnVLSAXVDw2yiHWOdSKSIwZABjdAgUTOyUALLK9NCrcAi7aMd6AIBvCyglqHKW4AAuanoqABoLAF8LcZsANymm7ETkqvnF5dX4jbYuHgEDSRldu6WULx8-TaRewxJyPK4pdL9HJ5P6FPbmQ6WMITKBnRogtodJDdYC9W7mZYrNabBQqNRaXT6UQfL4E5a-AoAhrAxxxFyYro9PpZHLwxHHSboxwBIHTHCzFholk4cE3SXnDHtTm4lBjcydHBlKCYNyAhXCygLOlLB4uEnbPlHdWasgAWySELSeqFOHxhNNpBJHG4fCE1OksnhhIZ-wIm2KVAAHlRqpakRrsFqUErsVzndLsG77sTqEpVBodHp3kYg-TYUyqAALbIITC0-nmABmRGwnRBUErcGwKAQEAAFCd02LsABKKBGwlIRtQAcAOg9ZHIS62DDHE8JywA9JvApgoCHCt8oPsoNkCNApzOTvO1hRl1Rva8-YZPmuj4Tt1BShUqtV38sEy1W0AmvA8-GKAAGWojxPM8L2nOcFzvShSXzCki39KQqDfY0N0-YYqn-JZALIQZKFA8sCFCQlEX2IA)

Comment: Relevant documentation: [discriminated unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions)